# Why can't I set a CORS policy to my Firebase storage bucket through the Google Cloud Console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I understand why a CORS policy is necessary, but why does firebase require me to install gsutil or gcloud tools in order to change the CORS policy of my firebase storage bucket? It would be way simpler if they allow you to do it through the Google Cloud Console.

Is it a security measure? Or am I just misunderstanding how CORS policies work?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Firebase Storage specific issue, but one from Google Cloud Storage. Simply put, there is no console configuration page for managing CORS.

Per the [Google Cloud Storage Bucket CORS documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-cors#configure-cors-bucket):

> You cannot manage CORS using the Google Cloud console. Use the `gcloud` CLI instead.

Per the [Google Cloud Storage CORS Support documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#server-side-support):

> Cloud Storage allows you to set a CORS configuration at the bucket level only. You can set up a CORS configuration for a bucket using the [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command-line tool, the [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview), or the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api). However, only requests made to XML API endpoints are checked against the CORS configuration that you set and can return responses that include the configured headers.

Based on the source for `gsutil`, there is [some preprocessing and validation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/6b65f9fe4a177c05a1a76fe04dc514c3c0498835/gslib/commands/cors.py#L173-L213) done to the configuration before it is committed to GCS. By requiring use of the API/CLI, a number of checks can be done to prevent user's locking themselves out, prevent malformed requests, mitigate session  hijacking and improve audit trails.